# Default arguments in function and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

1. Why can default arguments in C++ functions be considered polymorphism?
2. Why is it consider ad-hoc polymorphism and universal polymorphism?

I think that it can be considered as an ad-hoc polymorphism as its like overloading  functions(?), but in what way is it universal polymorphism?

Comment: lots of words... for one of the C/C++ feature I use the less.

Comment: What is *ad-hoc polymorphism* and *universal polymorphism*? Never heard of them!

Comment: @Nawaz: I Googled for it, and I found things like this: http://stason.org/TULARC/software/object-oriented-programming/2-1-What-Is-Polymorphism-Cardelli-and-Wegner-s-Definition.html...  But no, I'd never heard of it either!

Comment: Smells like homework to me, that question is way too buzzword-heavy to be a real question.

Comment: @Oli: Well that's why i said it's **theoretical**. I know both terms but still can't see why it can be considered as universal polymorphism.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yeah you are right but it's still a question..HW or not but apparently it's more than just knowing the terms.

Comment: @Oli: The link you've posted above does it.

Comment: We have a homework tag for homework.

Comment: @DeadMG: Well it's a theoretical question so wasn't sure if I had to place it there (no code as you can see) but okay, sorry for that then.

Comment: Please... one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is polymorphic, it has many shapes.

> In computer science, polymorphism is a
>   programming language feature that
>   allows values of different data types
>   to be handled using a uniform
>   interface.

As [this](http://stason.org/TULARC/software/object-oriented-programming/2-1-What-Is-Polymorphism-Cardelli-and-Wegner-s-Definition.html) link explains, there are different types of polymorphism. Ad-hoc polymorphism is what we call it when an interface defines different implementations depending on a *limited range of individually specified types and combinations*. Function overloading and default parameters is a great example of this.

Universal polymorphism is split into parametric polymorphism (when an interface is type independent - templates is a good example of this) and inclusion polymorphism (when one data type can be treated as another, i.e. the typical OOP polymorphism where a derived class may be treated as a base class).

When it comes to the default function arguments in C++, the ad-hoc polymorphism is quite obvious. The universal polymorphism might come from the fact that you can use C++'s inclusion polymorphic features with the function arguments:

```
void a_function (const char* print_me, Car* pCar = NULL)
{
    std::cout << print_me << std::endl;
    if(pCar)
        pCar->Drive();
}
```

Now, we could call the function like this:

```
a_function("Hello World!");
```

and it would simply print "Hello World!", or we can call it like this:

```
Car mycar;
a_function("Hello World!", &mycar);
```

and it would also drive the car. That is ad-hoc polymorphism. Due to C++'s inclusion polymorphism you can also do this:

```
class DieselTruck : public Car
{
     // ...
};
```

and call it like this:

```
DieselTruck mytruck;
a_function("Hello Earth!", &mytruck);
```

and it would drive the truck (if the classes were correctly set up, of course - virtual functions and all that). So you can mix ad-hoc and universal polymorphism in functions that way. Whether this is what your professor is thinking about or not, I do not know. It is not directly connected to default arguments - i.e. you can do this perfectly fine without them, but then again, I can't see how you could accomplish universal polymorphism in C++ using *only* default arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also had a feeling it has something to do with the inclusion polymorphism. Again, many thanks - well explained.

Answer (score 1):

1) It can be considered polymorphism because you're effectively providing different ways of calling the same function.  Consider:

```
int func(int a = 1, int b = 2, int c = 3, int d = 4);
```

I can call this the following ways:

```
func();
func(5);
func(5, 6);
func(5, 6, 7);
func(5, 6, 7, 8);
```

This way, it's similar to function overloading if we had provided these 5 different methods without any default arguments:

```
int func();
int func(int a);
int func(int a, int b);
int func(int a, int b, int c);
int func(int a, int b, int c, int d);
```

2) I, too, had not come across the term **ad-hoc polymorphism** until today, but my opinion is that it's *ad-hoc* because the number of types we can use, and the number of ways you can use it are all pre-determined.